# how to get android studio project libs for eclips?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i import a project into android studio but i want work with android studio and want work with eclipse . i don't have any problem with import into eclipse but i don't know how load libs into eclipse from Android Studio .

in Gradle :

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.1.0'
compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.0.6'
}
```

how get this libs from android studio ?

Comment: Go to projects properties->Android->Library (ADD), PS: you'll have to import library projects in the same workspace and folder as that of your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio uses an aar format for these libraries.

You can't use this format in Eclipse.

You have to build locally these libraries in your workspace.

- For support libraries you can follow this [guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res):
- For com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip you can clone this library from [github](https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip) and import the library folder as library project in eclipse (mark the java folder as source)
- For com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton you can follow the same way using this [repo](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton). In this case you can build a jar and put it in the libs folder.

BTW I suggest you using only Android Studio IDE.

Answer (score 0):

for  eclips.go to sdk\extras\android\support\v7 choose the project and copy jar file from the lib folder and past your project lib folder right click on jar file
 and add to bulid path. you can use all the class of project